# jQuery Multidatepicker Calendar opens and closes between date selection

Tags: jquery, widget, datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

I am using the [Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI](https://github.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI). When multiple dates are selected, the calendar opens and closes between each selection. How can I correct this so that the calendar stays open until all dates are selected and then only closes when it is clicked elsewhere in the browser.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
         <h3>On <a href="#" class="popover-tip" rel="popover"
                 data-content="Pick a date for your night out."
                 data-original-title="Date">
             <i class="icon-question-sign"></i></a></h3>
         <input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

```js
// Date picker - allows for multi select
$('.datepicker').multiDatesPicker({
    altField: '#altfield',
    dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",

    onBeforeShow: function () {
        $('#inputDate').DatePickerSetDate($('#inputDate').val(), true);
    },
    onChange: function (formated, dates) {
        $('#inputDate').val(formated);
        if ($('#closeOnSelect input').attr('checked')) {
            $('#inputDate').DatePickerHide();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting MultiDatesPicker from http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net. The version there worked for me.

Comment: Thanks naga. I did read through that and tried to add: 
 table.ui-datepicker-calendar {border-collapse: separate;}
 .ui-datepicker-calendar td {border: 1px solid transparent;}
to the css as they suggest, but it doesnt seem to have an impact

Comment: I cleaned up this answer, but I don't see how it could help since it looks like it's referring to the same project.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer i know but you can remove line 148:

```
(setTimeout('$("#'+inst.id+'").datepicker("show")',50);)
```

from `jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your requirement is that you want the calendar permanently open.

To achieve that you only need to change the input for a div.

In your html instead of

```
 <input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

put this

```
<div class="datepicker" style="display:block;"></div>
```

In case you want to have it open while selecting dates and then close it,you will have to show/hide it programatically probably using onfocus and onblur js events or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate:

Another answer notes that `jQuery UI defaulting to today's date when it can't parse several dates`. The codefix for `_setDateFromField` is here

[Multiple date picker - months jumping problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199601/multiple-date-picker-months-jumping-problems)